# How can I increase the request timeout in Java SDK v4 for Cosmos or Spring data for Cosmos v3?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to run an aggregate query to calculate the count of records e.g. `SELECT r.product_id, r.rating, COUNT(1) FROM product_ratings r GROUP BY r.product_id, r.rating`. The query works perfectly fine on the Azure Data Explorer, albeit a little slow. An optimised version of the query takes about 30 seconds when executed on the Data Explorer. However, when I run the same query in my Java app, it appears to be timing out in 5 seconds with the following exception:

```
com.azure.cosmos.implementation.GoneException: {"innerErrorMessage":"The requested resource is no longer available at the server."}
```

I believe this is due to a default request timeout of 5 seconds defined in ConnectionPolicy (both Direct and Gateway modes). I can't find a way to override this default. Is there a way to increase the request timeout? Is there another possible reason for this error?

Tried this both on the Java SDK v4 and Spring Data Connector v3 with the same end result i.e. `GoneException`.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following recommendations,

The following should help to address the issue:

- Try to increase http [**`connection pool size`**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/master/commons/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/ConnectionPolicy.java#L177) (default is 1000, you can increase to 2000)
- If you are using GateWay mode, try the DirectMode, more traffic will go over tcp and less traffic over http

You can refer the [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/3f31d68eed6fbe11516ca3afe3955c8840a6e974/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/CosmosClientBuilder.java#L765) code on setting the timeout.

Comment: I am using Direct mode already. Not sure how the connection pool size will help, since I am running only one query.

Comment: Ok i meant in general, you can refer this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-java-sdk-v4-sql?tabs=api-async. In this case you can refer the Timout part of the code